# Center Two Tables, Add Gap, and Keep Aligned HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the below HTML code to show the two tables in the center of the page with a slightly larger space between them and top vertical alignment because they may not have the number of rows in each table so i want them.

I've managed to get it top aligned but I can't seem to get them centered on the page.  Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<style>
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  #tbl1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  }
  #tbl2 {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #mytbl {
    display: inline-table;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
</style>
<div id="tbl1">
  <div id="tbl2">
    <table id="mytbl" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th style="font-size:25px" colspan="4" align="center" valign="middle">TN Staff</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="font-size:20px">Name</th>
        <th style="font-size:20px">Job Title</th>
        <th style="font-size:20px">Office</th>
        <th style="font-size:20px">Cell</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>John Smith</strong>
        </td>
        <td>Director of Operations</td>
        <td align="center">123-555-4567</td>
        <td align="center">123-555-0123</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="mytbl" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th style="font-size:25px" colspan="4" align="center" valign="middle">VA Staff</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="font-size:20px">Name</th>
        <th style="font-size:20px">Job Title</th>
        <th style="font-size:20px">Office</th>
        <th style="font-size:20px">Cell</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Jane Doe</strong>
        </td>
        <td>Director of Operations</td>
        <td align="center">321-555-7654</td>
        <td align="center">321-555-3210</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: note : you have to change id's by classes ! for a good html :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add this

```
#tbl2{
  text-align: center;
}

#mytbl{
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

Here's the full code:

```css
 html,
 body {
   height: 100%;
 }
 #tbl1 {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   display: table;
 }
 #tbl2 {
   vertical-align: top;
   text-align: center;
   display: table-cell;
   height: 100%;
 }
 #mytbl {
   display: inline-table;
   margin: 20px 0;
   ;
 }
```

```html
<div id="tbl1">
  <div id="tbl2">
    <table id="mytbl" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th style="font-size:25px" colspan="4" align="center" valign="middle">TN Staff</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="font-size:20px">Name</th>
        <th style="font-size:20px">Job Title</th>
        <th style="font-size:20px">Office</th>
        <th style="font-size:20px">Cell</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>John Smith</strong>
        </td>
        <td>Director of Operations</td>
        <td align="center">123-555-4567</td>
        <td align="center">123-555-0123</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table id="mytbl" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th style="font-size:25px" colspan="4" align="center" valign="middle">VA Staff</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="font-size:20px">Name</th>
        <th style="font-size:20px">Job Title</th>
        <th style="font-size:20px">Office</th>
        <th style="font-size:20px">Cell</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Jane Doe</strong>
        </td>
        <td>Director of Operations</td>
        <td align="center">321-555-7654</td>
        <td align="center">321-555-3210</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Advice: Don't use inline styles and do not place your style in the same document as your html code . Use a .css document to put all your styles and just add this in your html document( in head ):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="all">
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great.  I am using a style sheet just added to the above so you could get the whole reference.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<style>
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
    #tbl1 {
        display: table;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px;
}
    #tbl2 {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
}
    #mytbl {
    display: inline-table;
    margin: 0 auto 0 20px;
}
</style>
<div id="tbl1">
    <div id="tbl2">
        <table id="mytbl" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th style="font-size:25px" colspan="4" align="center" valign="middle">TN Staff</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="font-size:20px">Name</th>
                <th style="font-size:20px">Job Title</th>
                <th style="font-size:20px">Office</th>
                <th style="font-size:20px">Cell</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>John Smith</strong></td>
                <td>Director of Operations</td>
                <td align="center">123-555-4567</td>
                <td align="center">123-555-0123</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="mytbl" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th style="font-size:25px" colspan="4" align="center" valign="middle">VA Staff</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="font-size:20px">Name</th>
                <th style="font-size:20px">Job Title</th>
                <th style="font-size:20px">Office</th>
                <th style="font-size:20px">Cell</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Jane Doe</strong></td>
                <td>Director of Operations</td>
                <td align="center">321-555-7654</td>
                <td align="center">321-555-3210</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is a test: http://jsfiddle.net/on0xmmhq/

hope this help you

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.